# Death sentences in Spanish California

Tags: law, california, spanish-empire, crime, death-penalty

Ynocente Garcia, in his recollections (the "Garcia Hechos"), described [Ignacio Rochin](https://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=67246120), a man executed for murder in 1795 in Santa Barbara. Garcia continues: "a young orphan ... was also executed with Rochin for the crime of Sodomy...."

I want to know if this was a unique occurrence. I think criminals were technically supposed to be sent to San Blas or Guadalajara for trial, but that was clearly not as practical as creating justice locally.

How many people were judicially executed by the military establishment of Spanish California?

Comment: Seems to be some debate over events or at least dates here. According to [Bancroft](https://books.google.com/books?id=QugNAAAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA639&lpg=RA1-PA639&dq=jose+antonia+rosas+execution&source=bl&ots=ZxBvnSb0Bk&sig=fedE1J7yybSOlTPqYjewRXIk9Ck&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9uP-B0NjSAhXHv1QKHa6SDfMQ6AEIPDAI#v=onepage&q=jose%20antonia%20rosas%20execution&f=false]) the second execution you mention is Jose Antonia Rosas, and occurred in 1801, and seems to be fairly well documented.  This man was a soldier so was tried by order of a Commandant, so under military law.

Comment: Just looked at the link you provided above, and he was a soldier as well, so again under military law.

Comment: @user2448131 Jose Antonio Rosas and Anacleto Barbosa are the other two cases I've found, both soldiers. I don't think either of them correspond with the "orphan" that Garcia mentioned, though, so he might be apocryphal, or else did not get a Catholic burial.